# PhpStorm + Xdebug: how to debug nested CLI call

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

I've got PHP project `C:\project1` opened in PhpStorm that executes PHP code from another PHP project, `C:\project2`, opened in another instance of PhpStorm. Something like this:

```
// in project1:
exec('php ../project2/script.php');
```

When I start debugging in `project1`, breakpoints are hit fine. I'm trying to setup the other project so that when the code in `project2/script.php` executes, the breakpoints in the other PhpStorm are hit as well.

---

So far, I tried creating a function in project1 like this:

```
function runCommand($cmd) {

    $env = $_SERVER;       

    if (isset($_SERVER["XDEBUG_CONFIG"])) {
        $env['XDEBUG_CONFIG'] = 'idekey=project2 remote_host=127.0.0.1 remote_port=9001';
    }

    $process = new Symfony\Process($cmd, null, $env);
    $process->run();
}
```

but no joy, breakpoints in project2 are not hit.

Answer (score 1):

It works exactly as described in the OP, I just forgot that in the nested process, PhpStorm doesn't configure remote debugging automatically so I had to set the `xdebug.remote_enable` in php.ini manually.

Comment: In some scenarios, setting `xdebug.remote_autostart` is also useful.